# W3 Total Cache Minification - Any way to not use php?

Tags: plugin-w3-total-cache, nginx

I use nginx, php5-fpm and fastcgi_cache. W3TC minification seems good enough, but every include points to "minify.php?". I want to be able to keep my site up even if php and mysql server's goes down - surviving on cached (stale) versions of my pages.

Is there any way to not touch php for serving minified assets? I mean its already minified and probably gzipped, why does it need to go through .php? I am missing something?

My links look like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.domain.com.br/wp-content/plugins/w3-total-cache/pub/minify.php?file=bZBdjoMwDIQvtE6K9mV7msoEC2hDnI0daG6_odAfrXibGX-yxj5ZXShoIU8zBStaPH019hZHh4LQo_eUytNfdn9AyIAdLy3f36pSSwSXRXmiBInmkRY5yirZM_eewKGn0GGCtY6KdSK2dwTPYjsWfRbgQNBmVQ7QFrhNlYx8WUd1UtkryMBJHXe0Lbpi-R_v9dcWG_KbqzUfMXyb0-GyB2llYtYh0CuBPEJjfszZbFduX0jkMKob0L7UHw.css" media="all" />
```

Comment: Thanks alot. At first I had Rewrite URL structure ON and no rules on nginx side and was getting 404 errors on the assets so I disabled the option and completely forgot about it. Best regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. You are missing the rewrite rules that'll prettify the URLs of the minified assets.

Follow the instructions available for your setup at **WordPress Dashboard** > **Performance** (W3 Total Cache menu) > **Install**.